# Issue in importing snowflake connector

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Importing the statement:

```
import snowflake.connector
```

is giving the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package
```

I installed the package as per the official documentation:

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

NOTE: I've already tried the existing solutions to this issue, none of them work.
My Python version is **3.9.15** & the library installed is snowflake-connector-python **3.1.1**.

Comment: Has your installation succeed ? Can you find snowflake in the output of `pip list` ? Are you certain you are using the same python interpreter for lib installation and program execution ?

Comment: Yes, I have successfully installed the following --> snowflake-connector-python 3.1.1,
snowflake-sqlalchemy 1.5.0 and the interpreter too is same for both program execution & library installation.